# Monitor Spring java application

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to performance monitor spring java application?Jamon,Beet etc

Answer (score 4):

javamelody: http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/
Easy to integrate but throws exceptions if a security manager is enabled.

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#16. if a security manager is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

A spring application is no different in regard to monitoring than any other application. So use whichever tool you are familiar with / you like most.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to monitor the performance on the underlying app server you have deployed on. If Tomcat you have Lambda Probe.
for weblogic/websphere the consoles provide good in-life monitoring stats

Answer (score 0):

previous replies focused on performance monitoring and tuning.

however, there is another side in monitoring, this one being adressed by SNMP and its Java counterpart : JMX. Like [Spring documentation says](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jmx.html), JMX integration is quite straightforward.